# Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "a73aa084986c3e" using the following authenticators: "CRAM-MD5", "LOGIN", "PLAIN"

Tags: laravel, smtp, laravel-10, mailtrap

The issue: " Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "a73aa084986c3e" using the following authenticators: "CRAM-MD5", "LOGIN", "PLAIN". Authenticator "CRAM-MD5" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.0 Invalid credentials".". Authenticator "LOGIN" returned "Expected response code "334" but got empty code.". Authenticator "PLAIN" returned "Expected response code "235" but got empty code.".

I have updated my .env file but still having the same error.
.env file

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=a73aa084986c3e
MAIL_PASSWORD=********5ca2
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: Solved by running ```php artisan config:cache```, ```php artisan cache:clear```, ```php artisan optimize```, then restart the serve